# How to compute a Jacobian using polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the transformation $F$ of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ onto itself defined as
$$
F(x, y):=\left( \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right).$$
Its Jacobian matrix is 
$$\tag{1}
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & -\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \\ -\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \end{bmatrix},\quad \text{and its determinant equals}\ \frac{-1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$
The following alternative computation is **wrong** at (!) and (!!), and I cannot see why.

> Let $\phi\colon (0, \infty)\times (-\pi, \pi)\to \mathbb R^2$ be the map $$\phi(r, \theta) =(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta).$$ Let moreover $$\tag{2}\tilde{F}:=\phi^{-1}\circ F\circ \phi;$$ then, by an easy direct computation, $$\tilde{F}(r, \theta)=\left( \frac1r, \theta\right).$$The Jacobian matrix of $\tilde{F}$ is, thus, $$\tag{!}\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-1}{r^2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} , \quad \text{and its determinant equals }\ \frac{-1}{r^2}.$$On the other hand, by (2) and by the chain rule, the Jacobian determinants of $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ are equal. We conclude that the Jacobian determinant of $F$ is $$\tag{!!} \frac{-1}{r^2}=\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}.$$

The result (!!) is off by a factor of $r^{-2}$ from the correct one, which is given in (1). Equation (!) must also be wrong. Indeed, computing the Jacobian matrix from (2) using the chain rule, and using that 
$$
D\phi = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ 
-r\sin \theta & r\cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$$ 
and that 
$$\tag{!!!}
D(\phi^{-1})= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &  \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\ -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} & \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\end{bmatrix},$$
I obtain the result
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &  \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \\ -\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} & \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & -\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \\ -\frac{2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} & \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\ \sin \theta & r\cos \theta\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac1{r^2} & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{r^2}\end{bmatrix},$$
which is different from the matrix in (!), and which gives the correct determinant of $-1/r^4$, as it should be.

> Can you help me spot the mistake?

---

**SOLUTION** (*added at a later time*). As answerers pointed out, there is a mistake in (!!!). The correct matrix to be used is 
$$ D(\phi^{-1})|_{F\circ \phi(r, \theta)} 
= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}} &  \frac{\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}}  \\ -\frac{\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}}{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}  & \frac{\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}}{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin \theta \\ - r\sin \theta & r\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}.$$
Had I used this matrix, I would have found the correct result for the Jacobian matrix of $\tilde{F}$, which is the equation marked (!). Thus, (!) is actually **correct**.

My fundamental misunderstanding was the assumption that, because of (2), the Jacobian determinant should be invariant for coordinate changes. This is not true; what follows from (2) is only that 
$$
\det D\tilde{F}|_{(r, \theta)}= \det D\phi^{-1}|_{F\circ\phi(r, \theta)}\det D\phi|_{(r, \theta)} \det DF|_{\phi(r, \theta)}.
$$ 
The first two factors in the right-hand side **need not cancel**, as I erroneously thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any contradiction here.

Consider the volume form
$$ \omega_{\rm Cart} = dx \wedge dy.$$
Your first calculation shows that the pullback $F^\star(\omega_{\rm Cart})$ is given by
$$ F^\star(\omega_{\rm Cart}) = - \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\omega_{\rm Cart}.$$

Now consider the volume form
$$ \omega_{\rm Polar} = dr \wedge d\theta.$$
Your second calculation shows that

$$ F^\star(\omega_{\rm Polar})=-\frac 1 {r^2} \omega_{\rm Polar}. $$

We can use this to recompute $F^\star(\omega_{\rm Cart})$. In view of the fact that
$$ \omega_{\rm Cart} = r \omega_{\rm Polar},$$
we have:
\begin{align}
F^\star(\omega_{\rm Cart}) &= F^\star(r\omega_{\rm Polar}) \\ &= F^\star(r) F^\star(\omega_{\rm Polar}) \\ &= \frac 1 r \left( - \frac 1 {r^2}\omega_{\rm Polar} \right) \\ &= - \frac{1}{r^4} \left(r\omega_{\rm Polar} \right) \\ &= - \frac 1 {r^4} \omega_{\rm Cart}
\end{align}
which is consistent with the first calculation!

---

As for the application of the chain rule, we have:
$$ (D\bar F)|_{(r, \theta)} = D(\phi^{-1})|_{F\circ \phi(r, \theta)} (DF)|_{\phi(r, \theta)} (D\phi)|_{(r, \theta)}$$

The key point is that you must evaluate $D(\phi^{-1})$ at the point $\left(\frac x { (x^2 +y^2)}, \frac y {(x^2 + y^2)}\right)$, not at the point $(x, y)$.

This is equal to

$$ D(\phi^{-1})|_{F\circ \phi(r, \theta)} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}} &  \frac{\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}}  \\ -\frac{\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}}{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}  & \frac{\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}}{\left(\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} \right)^2+\left( \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2}\end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & \sin \theta \\ - r\sin \theta & r\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$$
which is *not* the inverse of $(D\phi)|_{(r, \theta)}$.

Comment: I couldn't expect a better answer. You nailed it completely. Also, thank you for suggesting the viewpoint of volume forms; that makes for much slicker computations.

Answer (score 6):

The Jacobians of the two functions aren't equal by the chain rule.

In actual fact, $D(\phi(\frac{1}{r}, \cos\theta)) × D\tilde{F}(r, \theta)= DF \times D(\phi(r, \theta))$

Comment: I accepted the other answer, but this one is also correct and useful, as I remarked in the "Solution" section, at the end of the question. Thank you.