# Total differential of the inversion around the unit sphere

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to compute the total differential of the inversion around the unit sphere, i.e.
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^n - \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^n - \{0\},\quad x\mapsto \frac{x}{||x||^2} = \frac{x}{\langle x, x \rangle}$$
using directly the defintion and not computing partial derivatives. So given $x\in\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$, I want to find a linear map L such that we have

$$ f(x + h) = f(x) + L(h) + o(||h||).$$

I have come this far

$$f(x + h) = \frac{x+h}{\langle x+h \rangle^2}= \frac{x + h}{||x||^2 + 2\langle x, h\rangle + ||h||^2}  = \frac{x + h}{||x||^2} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{2\langle x, h\rangle}{||x||^2} + \frac{||h||^2}{||x||^2}}$$

Now I want to use the fact that the 1st order Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1+t}$ is $1-t$, but am not sure how to go about it when t depends on x and h.
The way I would then proceed is

$$\frac{x + h}{||x||^2} \cdot (1 - \frac{2\langle x, h\rangle}{||x||^2} + o(||h||))
= f(x) + \frac{h}{||x||^2} - \frac{2x \langle x, h\rangle}{||x||^4} + o(||h||).$$

Comment: In the case $n=2$ "once upon a time", I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2621344/305862)

Comment: In your title "circle" is appropriate for $n=2$ ; otherwise, it is advisable to replace it by "(hyper)sphere".

Comment: "Once upon a time" I also wrote something about this problem. It is in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3198750/8157), which has received excellent answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use differential as the title of your question suggest it?

Using product rule for differentials,
\begin{eqnarray}
df
&=&
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
d\mathbf{x}
+
d\left( \|\mathbf{x}\|^{-2} \right)
\mathbf{x} \\
&=&
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
\left(
\mathbf{I}
-
\frac{2}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
\mathbf{x}
\mathbf{x}^T
\right)
d\mathbf{x}
\end{eqnarray}
since
$
d\left( \|\mathbf{x}\|^{-2} \right)
=
-2\|\mathbf{x}\|^{-3}
d\|\mathbf{x}\|
$
and
$d\|\mathbf{x}\| = 
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|}
\mathbf{x}^T d\mathbf{x}$.

In your notations
$$
L(\mathbf{h})
=
\frac{1}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
\left(
\mathbf{I}
-
\frac{2}{\|\mathbf{x}\|^2}
\mathbf{x}
\mathbf{x}^T
\right)
\mathbf{h}
$$
This indicates some errors in your formula but your reasoning seems otherwise correct.

Comment: [+1] Besides, this transformation formula, in the vicinity of the inversion (hyper)sphere is $\approx I-2XX^T$, which is a symmetry with respect to the hyperplane normal to $X$ generalizing the 2D case I refered to in my comment.

Comment: Basically the approach I outlined above is the solution to an assignement given to me and I am trying to understand the reasoning. But your approach is also helpful.

Comment: @Steph See my "answer" which bridges in fact your result and the calculations of "Universal Property".

Answer (score 0):

(Too long for a comment).

There are no errors in your calculations.

In fact, in your last expression, one can write :

$$\frac{h}{||x||^2} - \frac{2x \langle x, h\rangle}{||x||^4}=\frac{h}{||x||^2} - \frac{2x x^Th}{||x||^4}$$

Indeed, the dot product is equivalent to $x^Th$ where we have kept the notation $x$ and $h$ by assimilating these vectors to corresponding *column vectors* with respect to a certain basis. Factorizing $\frac{1}{||x||^2}$ on the left and "differential element" $h$ on the right, we obtain :

$$\frac{1}{||x||^2}\left(I - \frac{2x x^T}{||x||^2}\right)h$$

and... we retrieve the expression given by @Steph (multiplied by the differential element : you work with differentials, whereas Steph work with derivatives) proving that there is no error in your reasoning/calculations...

Comment: Thanks, I guess my problem is more how I get from the second to last math line to the final equality ...

Comment: In fact, I was mainly responding to the sentence "this indicates some errors" in the answer which has been given by "Steph".